# Implementing Sequentialfs

Tags: matlab, select, machine-learning, selection

I am trying to implement sequentialfs for feature selection. I saw this post : [Sequential feature selection Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288095/sequential-feature-selection-matlab)

Tried to follow the example given as the solution to implement.

My TrainVec is a matrix of dimension 268 x1475 whereas TestVec is 116x1475 and TestLabel is 116 x 1 and TestLabel is 268 x 1.

the code i implemented is

```
f = @(TrainVec,TrainLabel,TestVec,TestLabel) sum(TestLabel ~= predict_label); 
fs = sequentialfs(f,Vec,Label);
```

The error i get is :

```
??? Error using ==> crossval>evalFun at 505
The function
'@(TrainVec,TrainLabel,TestVec,TestLabel)sum(TestLabel~=predict_label)'
generated the following error:
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> crossval>getFuncVal at 524
funResult = evalFun(funorStr,arg(:));

Error in ==> crossval at 363
    funResult = getFuncVal(1, nData, cvp, data, funorStr, []);

Error in ==> sequentialfs>callfun at 495
    funResult = crossval(fun,x,other_data{:},...
```

I have checked all my matrixes and ensured that they are of same dimensions. Not sure what is wrong. Need some guidance.
    Error in ==> sequentialfs at 357
                    crit(k) = callfun(fun,x,other_data,cv,mcreps);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here if `predict_label` is a variable or a function with zero input arguments. I would guess that if it's a variable, it's not the same size as `TestLabel`; and if it's a function, it's either not returning something the same size as `TestLabel` or it has some intermediate calculation that is erroring.

Either way, you would typically want to be writing

```
f = @(TrainVec,TrainLabel,TestVec,TestLabel) sum(TestLabel ~= predict_label(TrainVec,TrainLabel,TestVec));
```

where `predict_label` is now a function that takes in your `TrainVec` and `TrainLabel`, builds a model, evaluates it on `TestVec`, and returns an array of predicted labels of the same size as `TestLabel`.

Comment: still not able to do it... Btw i am using LIBSVM for model prediction. Does it affect in anyway?

Comment: I have double checked. TestLabel and predict_label have the same dimensions... But the error still exist...

Comment: my values for the TrainLabel are -1 and 1.. Should it be 0 and 1 instead? does it make a difference?