# Simple Sequential feature selection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, select, machine-learning

I have a `40X3249` noisy dataset and `40X1` resultset. I want to perform simple sequential feature selection on it, in Matlab. Matlab example is complicated and I can't follow it. Even a few examples on SoF didn't help. I want to use **decision tree** as classifier to perform feature selection. Can someone please explain in simple terms.
Also is it a problem that my dataset has very low number of observations compared to the number of features?
I am following this example: [Sequential feature selection Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288095/sequential-feature-selection-matlab) and I am getting error like this:

> The pooled covariance matrix of TRAINING must be positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

I've explained the error message you're getting in answers to your previous questions.

In general, it is a problem that you have many more variables than samples. This will prevent you using some techniques, such as the discriminant analysis you were attempting, but it's a problem anyway. The fact is that if you have that high a ratio of variables to samples, it is very likely that some combination of variables would perfectly classify your dataset even if they were all random numbers. That's true if you build a single decision tree model, and even more true if you are using a feature selection method to explicitly search through combinations of variables.

I would suggest you try some sort of dimensionality reduction method. If all of your variables are continuous, you could try PCA as suggested by @user1207217. Alternatively you could use a latent variable method for model-building, such as PLS (`plsregress` in MATLAB).

If you're still intent on using sequential feature selection with a decision tree on this dataset, then you should be able to modify the example in the question you linked to, replacing the call to classify with one to `classregtree`.

Comment: In the example given on Matlab's documentation: http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/examples/selecting-features-for-classifying-high-dimensional-data.html, They have reduced dim of their feature set. Their dataset is 216X4000 which is also too much. Why can't I do dim reduction same way as them? I tried but I get same error as above.

Comment: You can try to do dimension reduction in the same way as the example given there. However, their dataset has more samples than yours, and fewer features. It's not 4000, it's 150 as they have applied a filter prior to applying `sequentialfs`. They also use the `nfeatures` parameter of `sequentialfs` to constrain it to select a maximum of 50 features, which is smaller than the number of samples, so they don't get the error you are seeing. Perhaps soon you will believe me that applying sequentialfs and LDA to a dataset of size 40x3249 is not a great idea. Try PCA, as has been suggested to you.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the use of the `classify` function in that question, which is performing LDA. This error occurs when the data is rank deficient (or in other words, some features are almost exactly correlated). In order to overcome this, you should project the data down to a lower dimensional subspace. Principal component analysis can do this for you. See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/pca.html) for more details on how to use `pca` function within statistics toolbox of Matlab.

```
[basis, scores, ~] = pca(X); % Find the basis functions and their weighting, X is row vectors
indices = find(scores > eps(2*max(scores))); % This is to find irrelevant components up to  machine precision of the biggest component .. with a litte extra tolerance (2x)
new_basis = basis(:, indices); % This gets us the relevant components, which are stored in variable "basis" as column vectors
X_new = X*new_basis; % inner products between the new basis functions spanning some subspace of the original, and the original feature vectors
```

This should get you automatic projections down into a relevant subspace. Note that your features won't have the same meaning as before, because they will be weighted combinations of the old features.

Extra note: If you don't want to change your feature representation, then instead of classify, you need to use something which works with rank deficient data. You could roll your own version of penalised discriminant analysis (which is quite simple), use support vector machines, or other classification functions which don't break with correlated features as LDA does (by virtue of requiring matrix inversion of the covariance estimate).

EDIT: P.S I haven't tested this, because I have rolled my own version of PCA in Matlab.