# Fails when using sequentialfs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use sequentialfs on a logistic regression in order to determine the variables to include. I have tried to modify the answer from here [Sequential feature selection Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288095/sequential-feature-selection-matlab) in order to make it work, but the handle part is tricky to me!

I am using

```
[b, dev, stats] = glmfit(X_train,y_train,'binomial','link','logit')
```

in order to fit a model, and then I use

```
y_hat = glmval(b,X_test,'logit');
```

to evaluate the model output. I have tried to make a handle

```
 f = @(X_test, y_test)...     
     (sum(y_test ~= round(glmval(b,X_test,'logit'))))
```

Which just says that I have "Too many input arguments", when I use

```
sequentialfs(f,X,y)
```

Can anyone help identify the relevant variables? A data set is below, where all variables will be deemed relevant, but the real problem is of a much larger scale which leads to overparametrization of the model.

X=

```
0,0305780001742986  0,0293310740486058  0,0289653631914407  0,0313646568650811  0,0308948854477814  0,0298740323895053
0,0221062699789144  0,0213746063391538  0,0196872068542263  0,0209915418572080  0,0206064713419377  0,0198587113064423
0,0275588428138312  0,0273957214651399  0,0291622596392042  0,0313729847567230  0,0314439993783026  0,0307137185244424
0,0262451954064372  0,0230629198767100  0,0251192876802874  0,0243459679829053  0,0235752627390268  0,0245208219450122
0,0232074343987232  0,0272778269415268  0,0288725913067116  0,0274565324127577  0,0283032894902223  0,0287391056368953
0,0237589488887855  0,0251929947662669  0,0209989755767701  0,0146662148369109  0,0193830305676060  0,0198900627308170
0,0275142606053146  0,0311683593689258  0,0287109246912083  0,0307544961383919  0,0293964246310913  0,0291758079280418
0,0284337063240141  0,0249820611584738  0,0261664330153102  0,0270312804219022  0,0269178494606530  0,0273467522864029
0,0279150521116060  0,0314021886143824  0,0291020356476994  0,0278247389567505  0,0294200854382611  0,0306460336509255
0,0270622115094110  0,0317795784913586  0,0278283619288299  0,0307757941373800  0,0292513615541838  0,0283900407512898
0,0270275432108930  0,0330384417745352  0,0323886885104962  0,0330255939800101  0,0329789138848656  0,0333091935226094
0,0263417729025468  0,0243442097895390  0,0253328659546050  0,0270828343149025  0,0262845355278762  0,0257915212526289
0,0247503544929709  0,0282150822748136  0,0282408722769508  0,0306907484707723  0,0284025718962319  0,0280291257508206
0,0282116130443164  0,0259317921438547  0,0316179116969559  0,0300579055064814  0,0315134680888256  0,0299693403497154
0,0221040769734790  0,0232354360252008  0,0231588261739581  0,0240414200785524  0,0209509517094598  0,0223174875964419
0,0264965936690525  0,0312918915850473  0,0297480867085914  0,0349060220702562  0,0307640365732823  0,0299291946182921
0,0283027112468824  0,0288419304885060  0,0275801208398665  0,0239401671924088  0,0263296648119700  0,0260497226349653
0,0298063469363023  0,0253535298515575  0,0245113899712628  0,0158158669753461  0,0228044538675689  0,0221885556611738
0,0276409442724517  0,0283430130710139  0,0303893043659674  0,0314511518633802  0,0315673022208602  0,0302375851656905
0,0270849987059202  0,0312381323489334  0,0301662309393833  0,0290482017036615  0,0299207348490636  0,0295746114571195
0,0225683074444599  0,0297455473987182  0,0241145950178924  0,0233857691372279  0,0259911200866772  0,0248345888658664
0,0267870191916224  0,0254332496269710  0,0270915983261551  0,0263567311441536  0,0267470932454238  0,0279742674970829
0,0271933786309775  0,0274722435013798  0,0249484244285920  0,0301299698898670  0,0255527349811283  0,0263901147510067
0,0262114755708772  0,0168593285634855  0,0205147916736994  0,0227484518393022  0,0187327306255277  0,0197581601499656
0,0314796048983783  0,0281771847088388  0,0318159664952504  0,0325586660052902  0,0315277330661507  0,0324593871738733
0,0265694239044569  0,0239306067986609  0,0263341531447523  0,0277011505766640  0,0274385429019891  0,0258861916796922
0,0248731179403750  0,0253801474063385  0,0258606627949811  0,0234446644496543  0,0262626821946271  0,0265908368467206
0,0268335079060221  0,0327877888534457  0,0292050848084788  0,0286811931594028  0,0288058286572012  0,0297311873407772
0,0289655102183149  0,0297912585631799  0,0289955796469846  0,0301374575223736  0,0286017508461882  0,0294957275181626
0,0291599221376467  0,0284752300175276  0,0294302899166185  0,0291600417637315  0,0304544724881292  0,0299842921064845
0,0306574107981617  0,0282562949634004  0,0290757741762068  0,0266759231631069  0,0276079132984815  0,0283490628634946
0,0251419690541645  0,0190208495552799  0,0219740565645893  0,0229700198654972  0,0231913971059666  0,0218104715761714
0,0279646047804379  0,0213712975401601  0,0266486742241442  0,0282351537040943  0,0256010069497723  0,0254151479565295
0,0291819765619095  0,0274841050997730  0,0277287252877124  0,0253910521460239  0,0270103968729900  0,0280719282161061
0,0267034888169756  0,0230641558482702  0,0254891453796317  0,0246876229024146  0,0232209026694445  0,0255548967304529
0,0282525579813869  0,0275995431014968  0,0263616638576222  0,0282844384170093  0,0262147272435204  0,0257109782177451
0,0293098464976821  0,0323503780295293  0,0266630772869637  0,0228075737924046  0,0263296732877124  0,0254313353506367
```

y=

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you use for `sequentialfs` should take in four variables. Yours only accepts two:

```
criterion = fun(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST,ytest)
```

This is because, even though you give only two variables, X and y, `sequentialfs` splits these into a training and testing subset (straight from the docs):

> Starting from an empty feature set, sequentialfs creates candidate
>   feature subsets by sequentially adding each of the features not yet
>   selected. For each candidate feature subset, sequentialfs performs
>   10-fold cross-validation by repeatedly calling fun with different
>   training subsets of X and y, XTRAIN and ytrain, and test subsets of X
>   and y, XTEST and ytest

So the function passed for `sequentialfs` must take both the training and test subsets, e.g.:

```
function criterion = my_function(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test)

    [b, dev, stats] = glmfit(X_train,y_train,'binomial','link','logit')
    y_hat = glmval(b,X_test,'logit');
    criterion = sum(y_test ~= round(y_hat));

end
```

If this function is on your path you can pass it as `@my_function`, you don't have to make an anonymous function to get a handle.

Comment: Thank you! Also for noting that it doesn't have to be an anonymous function!